# Laravel Model Concrete Properties

Tags: oop, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a lot of love for Laravel, it is one of the nicest frameworks I have used (I have probably used 50% php, RoR, Django, .Net). I am a little confused over why a model's property names are not declared inside the class or at least having an option to define them?

Something like below would be ideal, this would make it nicer to code in an IDE. I am sure there is a reason why it is built like this, I am interested to find out.

```
class Blog extends Eloquent
{
    public $id;
    public $blogTitle;
    public $date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent will automatically provide the model object with it's properties based on the columns in the database.

So it makes no sense to manually specify them, since Eloquent will handle it for you.

Everything you do manually could potentially be a source of error.

My guess is that this is the reason why.

Comment: You are right in saying that everything you do manually can be a source of error. That is my issue if you do not have the property in your class, you could easily mistype a property and create an error.